# Where to store value objects that can be updated by a user and displayed in a list to the user?

Tags: sql-server-2008, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to wrap my head around items that will be displayed in a drop down control of a web application and these items are value objects in my model. As an example, let’s assume I an entity named RFI (request for Information). That RFI has a value object named State. The possible state values as prescribed by the business are: Created, Open, Suspended, Closed. These values need to be displayed to the user and are updatable by the user (In some admin console). Since the values are only persisted on the entity, itself, what is the best method to store the list of possible values?

I am using a database (SQL 2008) and an ORM framework (Entity Framework 4.1), however I am not sure the database is the best place to store the possible values. I have heard of some users creating resource files (XML documents, CSV files, etc) for such things. What are others in the community doing in a scenario like this and what are some recommended best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lookup table in the database called "State" (or similar) with 4 rows.
This will be a foreign key in the "RFI" table.

Reasons:

- searching for "Closed" etc
- other client code will use it (it *will* at some point)
- it's relational...

Capture the model with Object Role Modelling for example and see what that produces.

Answer (score 1):

In my company we created a Lookup table in the database with an additional column that specifies the object each value is related to, and mapped the table multiple times with different object-key (We've implemented it in NHibernate and I'm not sure it is possible in EF, if not you could simply use Views instead) to different object-classes.

This will allow easy management as it is all stored in the db, with low maintenance as all the value-objects are stored in only one database (which makes it easier to cache).